# Download XML file from RSS feed

Tags: objective-c, xml, rss

as the title states, I'm trying to download the XML file from the RSS feed, however, I'm not sure how it is done in Objective-C, I've tried to use `stringWithContentsOfURL` for an `NSString`, however, that didn't work and I'm not quite sure why.

If anyone has any advice about how to achieve the download and why `stringWithContentsOfURL` didn't work please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

Location of XML file

```
NSString * url = @"www.example.com/somexmlfile.xml";
```

Send a simple HTTP GET request

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] 
                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                               timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
```

Save the response in an NSData object

```
NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

NSString* xmlFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The NSString above will contain your XML file.

Comment: The problem is I don't have a concrete url, only a feed://example.com url.  Edit: Solved, just replaced the feed with http

Comment: For future readers, one probably should only use `sendSynchronousRequest` if doing this from a background thread (e.g. dispatch or operation queue). If doing this from the main thread, use `sendAsynchronousRequest` or one of the many other asynchronous techniques.

Comment: Details of which can be found here - http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/